# How can I change the time and date for an app without changing my phone settings?

Tags: applications, date-and-time

I want to change the time and date for an app without changing my phone settings.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possibly need root access and some kind of Xposed/Magisk module to hook the Android API and modify the returned value for the specific package name...

Comment: If the app you want forge date and time for allows to be repackaged/resigned you could modify it and include Frida gadget in it. Then it would be possible to write a script and hook common date functions or directly the method that checks the valdit it's period. That works even on an unrooted phone.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the methods you can use to set custom time for specific apps:**

1. Xposed Hook - You can use Xposed modules that hook into date time functions inside the app. Everytime the app requests date time the module returns custom data. AppSettings, Xprivacy, Xprivacy Lua are few well known modules. (For using Xposed without root you can use taichi / virtualXposed)
2. Frida Hook - Just like Xposed you can hook date time methods to return different data. I cannot find an example of this, but it's very possible.
3. Patch Smali - You can decompile the apk and patch all date time calls with constant values. So it returns same date and time. Some thrid party cloner apps do this for you with nice GUI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).